# How To Remove Anonymous Image In Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-cli

So, I want to create an image for my app using

```
docker build .
```

But I forgot to give it a name and the name became `<none>`. When I tried to remove this with `docker image rm <none>`
The output is

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

How to remove this anonymous image?

Answer (score 1):

List images with

```
docker images --all
```

There you will find an image ID for each image, e.g:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx               latest              2622e6cca7eb        4 months ago        132MB
```

You can delete the image by image ID like this:

```
docker image rm -f 2622e6cca7eb
```